# Can i install more ram than product specs says it will handle?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a Compaq Presario sr2017cl running windows 8 pro 64bit, Athlon 64x2 cpu.  Specs. says I can only install 4x1g of ram.  I want to know if I can put 4x2g of ram into my machine.  If yes do I increase MHz, this is what I have now installed 4 sticks at 1g  PC2 5300 (667 MHz) DDR2 DIMMs.  Motherboard PASUS A8M2N-LA,
800w PSU.

Answer (score 3):

Can you physically?  Yes, well it work?  Most likely not.  This looks like a "budget" machine, where the manufacturer limits the machines capabilities.  4 GB of RAM on a 64 bit machines is an odd limit to have... And even if you *could* this would have no effect on the speed of the memory.

Comment: The motherboard is over 6 years old.  The memory limits are not that weird based on the processor chipset being used.  Its also limited to DDR2 memory which is half the reason there is such a small limit.

Comment: @RAMHOUND THIS IS FROM WWW.CPU-UPGRADE.COM,  am 2+ processor on A8M2N-LA


2009-12-03 07:55:06

Posted by: Marge C,

To Shelley,

HP will not add a new bios for this motherboard.(I actually asked) BIOS 5.07 is the newest. I have same board and can only get as far as BIOS 3.10(contacted them about 5.07 and got big NO). HP wants us to buy a new computer not upgrade our old one. 

Also to Josh about the RAM.

I now have 8 gigs on this board. 4 x 2gigs DDR2 800 pc6400. The ram I purchased is 1.8 volts.

Windows 7 x 64 recognizes all 8 gigs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

A machine may be able to *physically* handle more larger memory modules, but it may not be able to supply enough electricity to operate them properly, or the firmware/circuitry may not be able to access all of the larger module. There is no way to tell without looking further into the details of the system (which one may not have access to), or to, of course, just try it.